# How can I control the lengths of the axis lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This question is not about controlling the axis limits (I think), but rather about controlling the lengths of the axes lines themselves. I'm trying to make a ggplot (so that I can make use of its nice facetting capabilities) that is similar to a base R plot where the axes are manually added. These axes only extend as far as the last axis label.

Some setup data and the base R type of plot I'm trying to mimic:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("cowplot")
library("grid")

set.seed(5)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
D <- data.frame(x, y)

plot(x, y, axes = FALSE)
axis(1)
axis(2)
```

[image: Base R plot]

```
ggplot(D, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()
```

The default changes to ggplot from the `cowplot` package get pretty close:

[image]

But how can I tell ggplot to only draw the lines as far as the last axis label, even though points lie outside of that value (as in the base R plot)?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to modify the length of the axis line. Your best bet is probably to turn the axis lines off and use `annotate` (or `cowplot::draw_line`) to draw the custom lines you want.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Voting to close my own question.

Answer (score 16):

Well, @Gregor posted his comment while I was working on this, so here's the implementation. Just for illustrative purposes, the annotated axes are rendered in red to make it obvious they were added separately from the standard axis lines. If you're going to make a bunch of plots like this, you can also add some logic to programmatically determine the x and y limits for `annotate` and `coord_cartesian`.

```
  my_theme = list(theme_bw(),
                  theme(panel.border=element_blank(), 
                        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                        panel.grid.minor=element_blank()),
                  labs(y="",x=""))

  ggplot(D, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-1.4,1.4), ylim=c(-2.4,1.4)) +
    my_theme +
    annotate(x=-1.4, xend=-1.4, y=-2, yend=1, colour="red", lwd=0.75, geom="segment") +
    annotate(x=-1, xend=1, y=-2.4, yend=-2.4, colour="red", lwd=0.75, geom="segment")
```

[image]