# How to add lines of longitude and latitude on a map using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, spatial

I am now plotting the map of Canada using `ggplot2`. Because the default projection method is "aea"(Albers Equal Area), so the longitude and latitude are straight lines on the map.  I wonder how I can display the longitude and latitude in the form of "110W, 100W, 90W" and "50N, 60N, 70N" on the map. They should be curves. Thanks a lot.

The arcgis shapfile is downloaded from https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dcbcdf86939548af81efbd2d732336db
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
countries<-readOGR("Canada.shp", layer="Canada")
ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=countries,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill='white',color = "black")
```

The final result should be like this.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps see the [graticule package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/graticule/index.html), ([vignette here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/graticule/vignettes/graticule.html)).

Comment: Thanks. The website you provide is useful, but it does not work with `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `coord_map` argument of ggplot [documented here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_map.html)

This uses projections to alter the coordinate grid. Curved lines would include equal-distance projections, but you should look [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mapproj/docs/mapproject) for a list of all projections allowed. Which one you choose is a manner of preference.

Using `azequidistant` (I think this is the [Azimuthal equidistant projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection)), and adding labels manually:

```
axis_labels <- rbind(
                  data.frame(long = rep(-140,5),lat = seq(40,80,10), labels = seq(40,80,10)), # x axis labels
                  data.frame(long = seq(-140,-60,40),lat = rep(85,3), labels = seq(140,60,-40))  # y axis labels
)

   ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=countries,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill='white',color = "black") + 
  coord_map("azequidistant") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-140,60, by = 20))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(40,80, by = 10)) +
  geom_text(data = axis_labels, aes(x = long, y = lat, label = labels)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I try to run your code, an error occurs `Error in data.frame(x = x.range[1], y = y.major) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`. Do you know  how to fix this? I am using R version 3.3.1.       Meanwhile, as you can see, the axis tick labels are not in the right positions, that is, they are not close to the coordinate grid. Is there any solution as well? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YangYang try using this shapefile: http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif.action?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=gpr_000b11a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2040968&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/gpr_000b11a_e.zip. Does that still cause an error? and for the axis it looks as though you need to add manually using geom text. I will update later

Comment: Hi, I do not know why, but it works using the shapefile you give me. Maybe it is because the projection method for the shapefile I use before is `"aea"`, which is Albers Equal Area.

Comment: @YangYang hmm shapefiles should be able to move between projections without too much trouble. It may be more likely that your initial shapefile is corrupted. Are you able to use the one I linked instead?

Comment: I also just tried to run the shapefile you linked and it crashed my computer twice - the government of Canada one is better (and also doesn't violate the arcgis terms)

Comment: Thank you so much. The shapefile I use has crashed my computer as well and your shapefile is much better. Just one more question, in your code `geom_text(data = axis_labels, aes(x = long, y = lat, label = labels))`, what is the data for `axis_labels`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could always put that geom_point of the top 100 cities `maps::canada.cities[order(maps::canada.cities$pop, decreasing = T),][1:100,]`

Comment: Thank you so much and I really appreciate your kind help. I have been struggling with this problem for almost 2 weeks. You are amazing and definitely a master in R. The bounty is all yours! Thank you for your precious time. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. As you can see, the latitude lines are generally too long for Canada. Is there any way to shorten the latitude line to better fit the map? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YangYang you can set the limit of your axis like: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(40,80, by = 10), limits = c(40,90))`, but generally ggplot sets them appropriately to show all your data. I don't know what you mean by too long.

Comment: Hi, take latitude line 50 as an example, what I mean is that I hope latitude line 50 to cross the longitude line 140 just a little. Now, the latitude line 50 is "too long" for the map.

Comment: @YangYang gotcha - I think you have to play with the axis extent (which I am not that familiar with). See here (maybe) for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699650/how-can-i-control-the-lengths-of-the-axis-lines-in-ggplot

Comment: Thank you for your time. Cheers!

Comment: using coord_map is low efficient ,especially in large raster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate graticule layer of spatial data, which you then project based on your Canada layer.

You can find free graticule layers for download at [NaturalEarthData](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/).

```
countries<-readOGR("Canada.shp", layer="Canada")
grat <- readOGR("graticule.shp", layer="graticule")

grat_prj <- spTransform(grat, CRS(countries))

ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data=countries, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill='white',color = "black") + 
geom_path(data=grat_prj, aes(long, lat, group=group, fill=NULL), linetype="solid", color="grey50")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is an error `Error in CRS(countries) :  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(projargs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'`

Comment: Besides, your code will produce graticule for the whole world, but I only need the graticule to cover Canada. Thanks a lot.