# How to label scale values matching with gridlines when using coord_map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have map A from the code below.

```
usmp <- map_data("usa")
usamplt<-ggplot() + 
    geom_map(data=usmp, map=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region), fill = 'grey70')+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-60,-130,-5),labels=seq(-60,-130,-5),expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(20,50,5),labels=seq(20,50,5),expand=c(0,0))
    coord_map(projection="azequalarea")
usamplt
```

Map A
[image: MapA]

The odd thing about this map is both the labels in x and y are not matching with corresponding grid lines. It is not a problem in Map B.
[image: Map B]
 I know this is because of the projection `coord_map(projection="azequalarea").` I am wondering, in Map A how to label those points corresponding to grid line. i.e. I want to touch each grid lines by corresponding labels as in Map B but with new projection

```
coord_map(projection="azequalarea")
```

Comment: Workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38603405/3330437